# c++ generic lambdas: pattern type deduction

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, type-deduction, c++20

In C++20, under the proposal [Familiar template syntax for generic lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r2.pdf), the following code correctly deduces type T:

```
auto lamTest = []<typename T>(std::initializer_list<T> const & l)
{
    std::vector<T> v{ l };
    for (auto && e : v)
        std::cout << e << " ";
};
lamTest( { 1,2,3 } );
```

Is it possible to do this kind of pattern deduction in C++17 (or 14)?

Note: I am asking specifically about lambda expressions.

Comment: Ok, so why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it seems to me that the question doesn't show any research effort, and it is not apparently useful.

Comment: @cpplearner, actually did quite a bit of research on this, and found nothing. Looked on cppreference.com and other sites. After I posted, I did find an answer of sorts buried within the above cited paper. But that is a rather obscure source for what seems like a common problem. In fact, the paper outlines just how common a problem it is. As for it not being very useful, it's very useful if you're making extensive use of generic lambdas and don't have access or cannot use a C++20 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

That's standard function template deduction. It's no different from this:

```
template<typename T>
auto lamTest(std::initializer_list<T> const & l)
{
    std::vector<T> v{ l };
    for (auto && e : v)
        std::cout << e << " ";
};
```

Which (`std::initializer_list` aside) is regular C++98 code.

The only new thing C++20 is adding is the ability to write lambdas with an explicit template parameter list, rather than (or in addition to) C++14's `auto`. In every other way, it behaves just like any other template function.

Comment: So how do I deduce `T` in a C++14 lambda? That's the question.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: There's no `T` to deduce because you're not allowed to employ arbitrary template parameters in C++14. That's why C++20 is adding the feature. The *deduction* is not special; what's new is the ability to write as a lambda what you could have written as a regular function.

Comment: N.B. that you *can* get the `T` if you use an `auto` argument and then check `decltype(l)::value_type`, but that obviously means you are no longer constrained to initializer lists unless you also add a `static_assert` or some other check

Comment: @hlt: You can't put `auto` in the middle of a template type like with `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Comment: No, just `const auto& l` (that's why you need the `static_assert`)

Comment: @hlt, if I'm following you correctly, without using a `static_assert` to restrict the type of `l` there really is no way to do the pattern deduction I want.

Comment: Not in a single C++17 lambda, no (you could also use an `if constexpr`, but then what do you do if it *isn't* an `initializer_list`?)

Comment: @hlt, would you write that up as an answer?